# Adding a security certificate to a remote sql server

Tags: windows, sql-server, ssl-certificate, sql

I'm in the process of trying to add a security certificate to a sql server running on a remote machine. I managed to generate the cert, but I'm a bit lost on the next step. All the instructions I have found assume local access to the machine running the sql server instance. Does anyone know of instructions for how to do it remotely? Is what I want to do even possible?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can import a certificate from a network share. See [Transact-SQL - CREATE CERTIFICATE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-certificate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the specifics.